# Center and bold part of a text in Swift

Tags: ios, swift2

I want to center and bold the title of my paragraph. So far I can make the title bold but I cant center it.

Here's my code:

```
    let title = "Title of Paragraph"

    let attrs = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(15)]

    let boldString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:title, attributes:attrs)

    let normalText = "Something here.............."

    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:normalText)

    boldString.appendAttributedString(attributedString)

    label.attributedText = boldString
```

I tried to add another attribue in attrs:

```
    let attrs = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(15), NSTextAlignment: NSTextAlignment.Center]
```

I'm not sure if that's the correct way to center it, but it still gives an error  "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

I've searched the error but it seems I still can't fix the problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem is with the `NSTextAlignment` key  that you are trying to add on the dictionary. It's type is `Int` which becomes ambiguous with the previous key that is a `String` so I guess that's why the compiler is complaining. Either way `NSTextAlignment` is not a valid key to be used on `NSMutableAttributedString` attributes initialiser.

Maybe you are looking for something like that:

```
let string = "Any String"
let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.alignment = .Center

let attributes = [
    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(15),
    NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: style
]

let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string, attributes: attributes)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try a category on UILabel:

**UILabel+boldText**

```
func boldSubstring(substring: String) {

   var range: NSRange = self.text!.rangeOfString(substring)
   var attributedText: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: self.attributedText)
   attributedText.setAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(self.font.pointSize)], range: range)
   self.attributedText = attributedText

}

func centerAlginement(substring:String) {

   var paragraphStyle: NSMutableParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle.new
   paragraphStyle.alignment = .Center
   var attributedString: NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString.alloc(string: substring, attributes:  [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle])
   self.attributedText = attributedString

}
```

now you can use it in your view import category class to your view

```
myLabel.text = "DemoText"
myLabel.boldSubstring(myLabel.text)
myLabel.centerAlginement(myLabel.text)
```